# Visual Studio 2013 html entities & intellisense does not work

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, html-entities

the intellisense for & html entities does not work.
when i type & "in the ide editor source view".
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this is an error by design, thanks to MS.

the "HTML-Editor (Web Forms)" with split view does not support this function

the "HTML-Editor" works fine, but has no design view

Comment: by selecting a Editor from the Editorlist in the dialog "open with"